# Resizing in GWT

Tags: user-interface, gwt

Hello i want to resize my widgets in a Horizontal Panel
I use the following code (within the constructor of a class that inherits from HorizontalPanel)

```
            VerticalPanel left = new VerticalPanel();
    this.add(left);
    left.setSize("100%","100%");

    VerticalPanel right = new VerticalPanel();
    this.add(right);
    right.setSize("100%","100%");

    Button test = new Button("New button");
    right.add(test);
    test.setWidth("100%");


    Label newEval = new Label("New label");
    left.add(newEval);
    newEval.setWidth("100%");

    Button start = new Button("New button");
    left.add(start);
    start.setWidth("100%");
```

What do i need to add to make booth VerticalPanels and their child widgets resizing ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have called setWidth("100%") I'm assuming that's the problem. Try to use the setSize() method on the Button for example instead.